# Проблема с threading и multiprocessing в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing, threading

Есть готовый код, который запускает командную строку и выполняет операции, попутно логирует их.
Пытаюсь настроить threading python для более быстрой и оптимизированной работы, но при указании параметра ничего не меняется.
Код приложил. Может подскажет какие параметры прописать.

```html
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
import argparse
import requests
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "-t",
    "--threads",
    help="amount of threads (default: 1000)",
    type=int,
    default=100,
)
```

```html
args = parser.parse_args()

lock = threading.Lock()
```

```html
def main():
    with lock:
      ...
```

```html
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not getInternet():
        print(bcolors.RED + "No internet connection")
    makeDir()
    threads = args.threads
    pool = Pool(threads)
    for _ in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(main)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Код следует прилагать текстом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то собственно эта блокировка не даёт выполнять `main` более чем одному процессу одновременно, каждый следующий заходящий в `main` процесс ждёт, пока предыдущий процесс отпустит блокировку:

```
def main():
    with lock:
      ...
```

В результате у вас выполнение процессов получается последовательное, а не параллельное, и естественно никакого ускорения не происходит от того, что вы запустили много процессов.

Блокировка должна делаться только в так называемых `критических областях` кода, которые не должны выполняться одновременно, чтобы не нарушить целостность данных. В остальное время выполнения кода блокировку делать не следует, если вы хотите, чтобы код выполнялся параллельно. Блокировок должно быть как можно меньше и они должны быть как можно более кратковременными, если вы хотите достичь какого-то ускорения вообще. Нужно помнить, что есть ещё расходы на организацию многопоточности или многопроцессности и в каких-то случаях эти расходы могут перекрыть и даже превысить всю выгоду от параллельного выполнения кода.